# Could anyone explain the difference between the two users in mongodb3.4.5

Tags: node.js, mongodb, createuser

```
//the first user
{
    "_id" : "admin.guguji55",
    "user" : "guguji55",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "test"
        }
    ]
}

//the second user
{
    "_id" : "test.guguji66",
    "user" : "guguji66",
    "db" : "test",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

I create two users,the 'guguji55' could not connect my test database,but 'guguji66' could do it.I don't know why.my nodejs connection code is below:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://guguji66:du****kuan****@localhost:27017/test', function(err, db) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //the first user
    {
        "_id" : "admin.guguji55",
        "user" : "guguji55",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "test"
                }
        ]
}
 //the second user
{
        "_id" : "test.guguji66",
        "user" : "guguji66",
        "db" : "test",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "test"
                }
        ]
}
```

With reference to above block you created the first user (guguji55) for admin database. and second user (guguji66) for test database.
And you were trying to connect test database with the first user which you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain you the exact scenario, what happened with your users.
When you create the first user `guguji55` you were inside the database `admin`. so the user created with linking of `admin` database.

```
//the firsr user
{
    "_id" : "admin.guguji55",
    "user" : "guguji55",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

Second user is created inside the `test` database so its linked to test database that's why you can't access test database through the `guguji55`.

***Solution:***
Remove the first user `guguji55` and recreate it either without having inside in any database or inside in `test` database.

For more reference refer this
[link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/#db.createUser)

Comment: yes,I think so.what I don't understand is the field of 'roles'.as the reference of mongodb ,it could be a document({role:'readWrite',db:'test'}).doesn't it could have access to the database of test?